# Errors in javafx application

Tags: java

Below are some of the code I received from the same team member yesterday.

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;
import application.SplashScreenController;
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.SeparatorMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application { 

SplashScreenController spashScreen = new SplashScreenController();

private static Stage primaryStage;
private static BorderPane mainLayout;    

private static void showMainView() throws IOException {

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("MainView.fxml"));
    mainLayout = loader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(mainLayout);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();        
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {       
        spashScreen.showWindow();

        PauseTransition splashScreenDelay = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(3));

        splashScreenDelay.setOnFinished(f -> {

            primaryStage.show();
            spashScreen.hideWindow();

        });

        splashScreenDelay.playFromStart();          

        Main.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        Main.primaryStage.setTitle("Airline Reservation Application");
        showMainView();
        } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    launch(args);

}
}
```

And this is error code
    3월 31, 2018 4:34:34 오후 application.SplashScreenController 
    심각: 
    javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
    /C:/Users/missi/eclipseworkspace/AirlineReservationPractice/bin/application/SplashScreen.fxml

```
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2571)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
at application.SplashScreenController.<init>(SplashScreenController.java:45)
at application.Main.<init>(Main.java:40)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$160(LauncherImpl.java:819)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2566)
... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at application.SplashScreenController.initialize(SplashScreenController.java:79)
... 27 more

javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/missi/eclipse-workspace/AirlineReservationPractice/bin/application/MainView.fxml

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2848)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2692)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2661)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2517)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
at application.Main.showMainView(Main.java:49)
at application.Main.start(Main.java:73)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.TextField
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2916)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2905)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2846)
... 16 more
```

How can I start to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: according to the stack, you have an issue at SplashScreenController line 45. It is not presented in your code. Usually this issues happen when you misspell an fxml field in the struct and fxml loader does not recognize it.